# Initialise bs-timepicker with utc

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the following code to create a timepicker  (source: http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/datepicker#timepickers). But I can't initialize the time. It keeps initializing local time while  I want another. What am I doing wrong?

**html**

```
<input id="txtContrStartTimeTime" name="txtStartTimeTime" type="text"
       class="form-control"
       ng-model="time"
       bs-timepicker data-show-meridian="false" data-minute-step="1"
        >
```

**JS**

```
$scope.time = new Date(546541685565); //somewhere in 1989
    console.log("time first", $scope.time);
```

Comment: Link to plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Comment: plunkr link is busted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to disable a default time being set and change $scope.time to "hh:mm" format.

```
 data-default-time="false"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$scope.time = new Date(new Date(546541685565).setMinutes(0));
```

As done in the plunkr of the widget:
http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

EDIT:
Actually it should work without setMiutes(0). Are you sure, you're setting the right model?